# On Normality of a subgroup of a finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group such that $G=AB$, where $A$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$ and $B$ is nilpotent also $B \unlhd G$. Then why $A \cap B \unlhd G$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since  $B \unlhd G$, we get $A \cap B \unlhd A$. So to prove that $A \cap B \unlhd G$, you only need to show that $A \cap B \unlhd B$. If that is proved then certainly $A \cap B \unlhd G=AB$. We show that $A \cap B$ is maximal in $B$. Since $B$ is nilpotent, this implies that $A \cap B \unlhd B$. Assume that $A \cap B \subsetneq M \subsetneq B$ is a subgroup of $B$. We can choose $M$ to be maximal, whence normal by the nilpotency of $B$. So $AM$ is a subgroup, hence, $A$ being maximal, there are two cases: $AM=A$ or $AM=G$. In the first case, $M \subseteq A$. But also $M \subseteq B$, so $M \subseteq A \cap B$, a contradiction. In the latter case, $AM=AB$, so $B=B \cap AM=$ (applying Dedekind's Rule) $=(B \cap A)M=M$, again a contradiction.

Comment: Excuse me Dear Nicky Hekster, i have a question. Since $B$ is nilpotent and $M$ is maximal in $B$, we get $M$ is normal in $B$. In this case why $MA$ is subgroup? Is $M$ normal in $G$ or $M$ char $B$?

Comment: You have a good point there, and I do not see how to repair it. Allow me some time to revision this.

Comment: By the way, where did you pull the question from? A textbook or a paper?

Comment: It is a question that my professor asked me to solve.